# Very low water pressure coming out of cooper tub spout pipe

Tags: water

My Co-op recently turned off my buildings hot & cold water supply to fix some pipes. Everything seemed OK for a few weeks, but now the water pressure coming out of the tubes cooper pipe (after the Delta cartridge) is very low pressure.  I tried removing the cartridge (RP46463) and installing a new one - doing this evidently caused some rust or sediment to dialoged and it cam pouring our.  After I installed the new cartridge the water pressure remained low coming out of the cooper tubing. I am thinking I need to have my co-ops plumbers come and use there equipment to blow out the water line for the tub/shower.  I do have another new RP46463, but I wont install it until after the lines get blown out. I'm not sure that is the problem, I have already used a vacume that has a blower on the tube and shower and that did force water through the lines but the pressure remains low.

If anyone one has any ideas or suggestion it would be greatly appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Co-op's "plumbers" came this morning and they finally used a hand tool which they refer to as a "Blaster", they first used it on the hot/cold valve with the cartridge removed - the flow got a little better - then I asked them to use it on the tube spout copper pipe - after several attempts BINGO, FULL pressure water flow has returned. There was evidently "something" between the hot/cold valve & the tubs copper spout that needed a really strong push to get knocked out.  All we saw was some brown water and a few very small pieces of rust.  This is the 3rd time this has occurred this year, so I have become an unfortunate experienced person at what needs to be done.  If I had a "blaster" I likely could have taken care of it and I might just get one.